# What would be consider as my local scope in this function?

Tags: javascript

just wondering what would be considered as my local scope in this function? Just a tad confused.

```
function hello(name, age) {
    var message = name + ", who is " + age + " years old, says hi!";

    return function sayHello() {
        console.log(message);
    };
}

var sayHelloToJohn = hello("John", 33);

sayHelloToJohn();
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you mean correctly, in your case, `message` and `sayHello` are local variable/function. That means they cannot be assigned from the outside `hello` function.

But notice that, if you remove `var` keyword from

```
var message = name + ", who is " + age + " years old, says hi!";
```

it **can** be assigned from the outside of `hello` function. Same to `sayHello` function:

```js
function hello(name, age) {
    message = name + ", who is " + age + " years old, says hi!";

    sayHello = function () {
        console.log(message);
    };

    return sayHello;
}

var sayHelloToJohn = hello("John", 33);

sayHelloToJohn();
console.log(message);
sayHello();
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking for the definition of the English word **local**? It just means "in the area". It's a relative term. The local scope is the scope of what you're currently talking about. When we speak of a variable local to a function, we mean that the variable isn't accessible outside said function.

When you declare a variable with `var`, it exists within the nearest enclosing function. When you declare a variable with `let`, it exists within the nearest enclosing braces `{ ... }`.

In the example you've provided, 3 scopes were created:

- The global scope which contains `hello`, `sayHelloToJohn`
- `hello`'s scope,  which contains `name`, `age`, `message` and `sayHello`
- The scope of the `sayHello` function.